# Segmentation fault which is happened when are imported some libraries in Python?

Tags: python, linux, segmentation-fault

I've install python2.7 on my controller with linux 2.6.11 (BusyBox). I ran python2.7 - all normal. import os - all ok. But when i import libraries, which is required shared object files from python2.7\lib-dynload (import random, import io and etc) i have Segmentation fault error. What's the problem ?

[image]

If i try to rename, for instans _io.so to _io2.so then i have the following error:
[image]

Comment: Please post the stack trace from `gdb`

Comment: i can't install gdb while... :(

Comment: Seems you compiled Python yourself using gcc 3.4.3., released in 2004.  Why did you use such an old compiler?

Comment: i compiled python on old linux (with similar version of libs) and copy files to comtroller

Comment: thats probably why it segfaults... You need to compile with the exact same library versions otherwise bad things like that happens.

Comment: did you use buildroot to create this environment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to find out why something segfaults is to install Valgrind and run it with that. However that may not work on your controller. If you have a more powerful machine with the same architecture, or even a QEMU emulated copy of the same Linux binaries on a more powerful machine, then you could use that to do Valgrind debugging.